# Is Possible to add in between UITableView sections in google Admob in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, admob, googleads-mobile-unity

I have 10 sections in `UITableview`.

I want to add `AdMob` in between `UITableview` Sections.

Is it possible means any code reference?

Comment: do you want to add adMob banner between sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(documentArray.count>0)
    {
        NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
        if (row==3) {

}
else
{
}
```

Comment: How does it answers the question?